# Defining custom Python skeletons

Tags: python, skeleton, python-mode

I'm trying to define a custom Python skeleton and have found there are two macros in [`python.el`](https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode) that might be of use here.

After poking around and looking at the value for `python-skeleton-autoinsert` it revealed there is...

### `python-define-skeleton`

```
python-mode-skeleton-abbrev-table is a variable defined in
python.el.gz.

Value
[## 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 def 0 0 class 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 try 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 while 0 0 0 for 0 0 0 0 0 0]

Set

Documentation
Abbrev table for Python mode skeletons.
```

`Value` is slightly confusing but I also found...

### `python-define-auxiliary-skeleton`

```
python-define-auxiliary-skeleton is a macro defined in python.el.gz.

Signature
(python-define-auxiliary-skeleton NAME &optional DOC &rest SKEL)

Documentation
Define a python-mode auxiliary skeleton using NAME DOC and SKEL.

The skeleton will be bound to python-skeleton-NAME.
```

### Aim

My aim is to have a skeleton that inserts the following (correctly indented for the position but I think that is taken care of by the functions), getting a prompt for the `<value>` and inserting it so that the output is...

```python
print(f"{<value>=}")
```

### First Attempt

Tried the following and it evaluated without error...

```lisp
;; Define a skeleton for printing
(python-define-auxiliary-skeleton print-debug
  "Insert a print statement that will show the value of the argument."
  "Enter the variable/object name: "
  "print(f\"{" str "=}\")")
```

Checking the value of `python-mode-skeleton-abbrev-table` this hasn't been added though.

### Questions

1. I don't understand what the values of `&optional` and `&rest` are so I'm unsure if I'm defining this correctly.
2. Once I've got the definition correct how would I get this included in `python-mode-skeleton-abbrev-table` (or otherwise registered/recognised) so that the skeleton is available with the others (so I can bind it to a key sequence)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the python skeleton commands, you will find their names use a single dash after the 'namespace'. Using your `print-debug` definition example, the created `python-skeleton--print-debug` has two dashes after after the namespace part. So we jump to the python-skeleton definitions (using `M-x find-function`). We find that they have been defined using `python-skeleton-define` and that `python-define-auxiliary-skeleton` has been used only for 'auxiliary' skeletons (skeletons used by other skeletons, like the `else` skeleton in the `if` skeleton).

So you should simpy replace `python-define-auxiliary-skeleton` with `python-skeleton-define` in your exmple definition and your code will work fine (the functions take the same arguments, and you have interpreted &optional and &rest correctly. You can find their meanings in the elisp documentation).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, as you say works as expected. I found a useful description of how `&optional` and `&rest` work at http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_optional_params.html should anyone else come across this.

Comment: Another description can be found in the Elisp manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html).